# Get author total post votes from post meta

Tags: custom-field, query-posts, author, post-meta

In author.php, i have the list with the posts written by the author.
I'm trying to get the total number of votes, from the author posts.
All posts have a post_meta with a numbered value. i need to count the total votes from all the posts that made from this user/author.

Is that possible? is a query available, that can handle this request?

thanks a lot!

Comment: The database table _wp\_postmeta_ has 4 columns - under what _meta\_key_ are the votes saved? If you don't know that - what plugin are you using?

Comment: i'm not using a plugin, every post haves a "votes" meta key with a numbered value. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a loop within your *author.php* file, grab the required metadata for every post within it, add it into a variable and display that after the loop has finished:

```
$author_vote_count = 0; //declare vote count variable before the loop

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    // the stuff going on in your loop already

    <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'votes', true) ) {
        $author_vote_count = $author_vote_count + get_post_meta($post->ID, 'votes', true);
    } ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php echo "Total votes on author's posts: " . $author_vote_count; ?>
```

The above will only work as expected, if the *meta_value* of the key *votes* is an integer (or any type of number). Should it be saved in the database as a string, you need to convert it to an integer first. In that case use

```
$author_vote_count = $author_vote_count + intval( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'votes', true) );
```

instead.

Comment: it returns the total number of the latest post by user

Comment: i leave it open to get some answers! thanks a lot!

Comment: @Philip Have you by any chance put the `$author_vote_count = 0` inside the `while` loop? Or are you trying to use the above on single post pages? If neither is the case, this will work as it should. If your _author.php_ lists all post by an author and you've put the above snippets in their respective places they will return all votes on all posts by that author.